# Opencv Join bounding boxes python

Tags: python

i have a haar detection and it produces me some nearby detections:

```
[[ 31  85 232 116]
 [141  55  66  33]
 [112  41 104  52]]
```

each list have the following values: `x,y,w,h`
id like to get the most left top `X,Y` and the most right bottom `x,y` of all detections.

i tryed to use `min()` and `max()` but ot produces a error.
and after that i tryed to use Numpy and i canot make what i need

```
import numpy as np
l = [10, 22, 8, 8, 11]
print(np.argmax(l))
print(np.argmin(l))
```

in my problen the list should be the list  of lists and i want to get only lesser `x,y` and higer `x,y`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = [ [ 31,85,232,116],
 [141,55,66,33],
 [112,41,104,52]
]
```

You can use a custom key with the values of first 2 elements to get max and min value. Since you need to draw a bounding box around all boundingboxes, you need to find min of `x,y` pair and max of `x+w,y+h` pair

This assumes x,y values are always positive which is fine in a image scenario.

```
min(x,key=lambda x:(x[0],x[1]))[:2]
max([(e[0]+e[2],e[1]+e[3]) for e in x ])
```

Out:

```
[31, 85]
(263, 201)
```

Comment: i need the following output: (x1: 31,y1:41, x2:141, y2:85)

Comment: So it's like `min of 1st value`, `min of 2nd value` and `max of 1st` ,`max of 2nd`  ?

Comment: i need to draw a bounding box arround all boundingboxes returned in my detection

Comment: then shouldn't the answer be `31,85` and `(263, 201)`? the lowest `x y` and the highest `x+w,y+h`

Comment: Updated my answer let me know if that is what you are looking for